# Form will not display results

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

**Problem:** The form works fine in chrome, firefox, safari and IE 9 to current version. However, in IE8, the form does not work.

By not work, what I mean is when you select a city in the drop down box and select enter, the page just refreshes. It applies to the other textbox/dropdown boxes on the form.

[image]

The following is the path to the page: http://www.regalmed.com/index.cfm/urgent-care-finder/

I have tried to copy and paste what I have done to the other pages and replace it by manually doing what I did on the form, but it continues to refresh the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** The following is the form. The only thing I can think of is that the placeholder is being read at the beginning. Meaning, when the form loads, it considers the placeholder "Zip Code" and an error appears in the bottom. Not sure what is going on

```
    <!---<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.min.css" />
<![endif]-->

</head>

<body>--->  
<cfquery name="UCarecityFind" datasource="Data">
    SELECT Distinct officecity FROM UrgHosp
    where utilizedspecialty in (<cfqueryparam value="#name_list1#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
    and network not like (<cfqueryparam value="#'%name_list2%'#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)
    and Company in (<cfqueryparam value="#name_list3#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">)  
    order by officecity
    </cfquery>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form name="UrgentCareSearch" ng-submit="SearchUrgentCare(searchParam);" novalidate="" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" id="urgentcare" ng-model="searchParam.UrgentCareName" placeholder="Urgent Care Name" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <SELECT name="proCity" class="form-control margin-bottom1" placeholder="City" ng-model="searchParam.City">
                <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">City</option> 
                <option value=""></option>
                <cfoutput query="UCarecityFind">
                <option value=#officecity#>#officecity#</option>
            </cfoutput>
            </select>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div style="margin-top:-10px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; font-size:8pt! important">* or Search by Zip code radius *</div>

        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-7 no-right-padding">
        <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group"><select class="form-control" name="distance" ng-model="searchParam.Distance" ng-options="mile.value for mile in miles"><option selected="selected" value=" "></option><option >5</option><option>10</option><option>15</option><option>20</option></select>
        <div class="input-group-addon">miles</div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 no-left-padding widthZip">
        <div class="form-group"><input allow-pattern="[\d\W]" class="form-control" id="zip" maxlength="5" ng-model="searchParam.Zip" placeholder="Zip code" type="text" /></div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group"><input class="btn btn-warning btn-block" ng-click="gotoElement('SearchResultsAnchor');" type="submit" value="Search" /></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var probablyPhone = ((/iphone|android|ie|blackberry|fennec/).test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);

    function initialize() {
        (function($) {
            $('.call').css("text-decoration", "none");
            $('.call').css("color", "black");
            $('.call').css("cursor", "default");
        })(jQuery);
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#zip').on("change",function(){
        $('#city option[value=""]').prop('selected',true).trigger('input');
        /*console.log('input');*/
   });

    $('#city').on("change",function(){
       $('#zip').val('').trigger('input');
       /*console.log('change');*/
    });
});
</script>

<!---
</body>
</html>
--->
```

Comment: My observations are that if the focus is in a dropdown, and you press enter, nothing happens.  With textboxes, checkboxes, etc, pressing enter submit the form.  I'll interpret that as default browser behaviour.  Are you trying to achieve something different?  If so, what are you trying to achieve and how are you trying to do so?

Comment: @DanBracuk When the user enters a city, for example, it will grab a list of urgent cares within that city or surrounding cities. However, instead, it goes and throughs an error of the bottom of the page.

Comment: I have tested your form in IE8 and I get the error that angular is undefined in the lower left corner of the browser, is that on your end same or you have some other errors @RobertoFlores

Comment: @oserk I have resolved the issue. I was able to create a scrip that handles undefined characters. Thank You, your help helped me come to a resolution

Comment: great @RobertoFlores please mark the answer as solution if you fill that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE8 you need a shim to be included,, please try that to see if that works..

https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

take a look here also:

https://github.com/NantHealth/AngularJS-IE8-Shim

hth, k

Comment: @ oserk: I have tried this approach but it does not work. I believe it has to do with the placeholder, meaning the text in the dropdown and textboxes and so forth